# How to subtract numbers with dots in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example I have 3.6.12 and I need to subtract 1.2.2,

```
3.6.12 - 1.2.2 = 2.4.10
```

But how to do it in js?

Upd: I found solution how to do it without numbers with minus before. Here is example:

```
a = '10.1.20';
b = [2,4,30]
let res = [];
a.split('.').map((val, index) => {
let cur_res = parseInt(val-b[index]);
    if(cur_res < 0){
      res.push(parseInt(Math.pow(10,val.length)+parseInt(val) - b[index]));
    res[index - 1]--;
  }else{
      res.push(parseInt(val-b[index]));
  }
});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Here is a hint: use `split()` to create two arrays.

Comment: What about `3.6.12 - 1.2.2.8`? Or what happens with `3.6.12 - 1.2.20`?

Comment: what about negative values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `split` the strings into arrays to get the numbers, then parse them as ints and subtract them, and then re-join into a string with periods between.

```js
function subract(a, b) {
  a_nums = a.split('.')
  b_nums = b.split('.')
  return a_nums.map((n, i) => parseInt(n) + parseInt(b_nums[i])).join('.')
};

console.log(subract("3.6.12", "1.2.2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, below is one of the ways.

1. Convert string into a number array using split.
2. Convert string value to number type using the array map method.

> I've combined first and second in one step

3. Iterate and find the difference. You can iterate using the old `for` loop but I've used the `map` method as it will give us our result in an array.
4. combine/join the array with a separator.

```js
function getDifference(first, second) {
  const firstNumberArray = first.split(".").map((x) => parseInt(x));
  const secondNumberArray = second.split(".").map((x) => parseInt(x));

  const resultArray = firstNumberArray.map((num, index) => {
    return firstNumberArray[index] - secondNumberArray[index];
  });

  const finalResult = resultArray.join(".");
  return finalResult;
}

const first = "3.6.12";
const second = "1.2.2";
const result = getDifference(first, second);
console.log(`${first} - ${second} = ${result}`);
```